# ArrowIOError occurred reading from BigQuery with google-cloud-bigquery client library (Python)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, pyarrow

I had a function to retrieve a pandas dataframe from a query to BigQuery which worked perfectly for the last couple of months.
Today, without any changes, it stopped working in GoogleColab Notebooks throwing this exception:

> An exception of type ArrowIOError occurred reading from BigQuery.
> Arguments: ('Cannot read a negative number of bytes from
> BufferReader.',)

My code:

```
def read_from_bigquery_client(bq_client, project_id, sql, curr_func):
  try:
    df = bq_client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()
    return df
  except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred reading from BigQuery. Arguments:\n{1!r}\nFunction: {2}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, curr_func)
    print(message)
    return None
```

Client Auth:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(local_cred_filename)
bq_client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials,
                            project=credentials.project_id)
```

The queries I have tried work perfectly when applied directly to BigQuery, plus they worked previously as mentioned above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi! Could you please share the google-cloud-bigquery lib version, by typing: `pip freeze`
? The new version (1.26.0) has been released today, which could cause the issue: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/#history

Comment: Hi! Yes, its in version 1.26.0.
The problem is probably due to the version update, since I just tried downgrading to the version 1.21.0 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [new version](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/#history) (1.26.0) of `google-cloud-bigquery` Python library has been released on 22nd of July. It may occur issue, that haven't been detected yet. The similar issue with corresponding version has been already reported on [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/177), where you can follow the updates. Additionally, please report the error you have encountered as well.

As for now, the workaround for `ArrowIOError` is to downgrade the version of `google-cloud-bigquery` library.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the version of `google-cloud-bigquery` to 1.24.0 , still the error is intact.
Other versions are :

```
pyarrow==0.11.1
pandas==0.23.4
pandas-gbq==0.7.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until I upgraded my pandas package, which apparently I saw from the documentation, a version of pandas higher than 0.29.0 can use `google-cloud-bigquery` well

The best way to update pandas was:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```